# Camera image is not saving in sdcard and does not display in imageview in front camera in android

Tags: android

I am using the front camera to take a picture and display it in image view, but the image is not captured using frontface camera in samsung galaxy tab. Can anybody tell what the problem is? Even I had given set picture format. I used getoptimalpreview size for preview size. Can anybody tell me if I missed anything? Preview is showing properly but clicking 'take picture' background is black

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.set("camera-id", 2);
params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
```

saving and setting display in imageview

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
String filename = "vijaypicture.jpg";
File pictureFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename);
try
{
FileOutputStream pfos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, pfos);
pfos.flush();
pfos.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: writing a custom camera is a painful attempt, take atvantage of default android camera app by calling the intent.

Answer (score 2):

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {           
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                    "/sdcard/test/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            Log.d("", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        Log.d("", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
    }
```

Hope that this helps, make manualy create a folder or use the mkdir command in your code to create the folder, and build a check if it already excists